How to refresh access token acquired from Firebase linked provider
How to refresh expired access token of microsoft provider which I am getting using microsoftUserCredential?.user?.refreshToken, I tried extracting refresh tokens as shown in below code and sending request to microsoft api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=curl#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-renew-an-expired-access-token
But I am getting error :
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: 9725f9f0-67c9-40b2-8628-cf80187b1200 Correlation ID: 71940d3f-e4bf-4d9b-9e34-f4a6afa0b319 Timestamp: 2024-07-06 06:25:30Z",
"error_codes": [
9002313
],
"timestamp": "2024-07-06 06:25:30Z",
"trace_id": "9725f9f0-67c9-40b2-8628-cf80187b1200",
"correlation_id": "71940d3f-e4bf-4d9b-9e34-f4a6afa0b319",
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
Future<void> signInWithMicrosoft() async {
final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user == null) {
  throw Exception("Not signed in");
}

final MicrosoftAuthProvider microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
microsoftProvider.addScope('email');
microsoftProvider.addScope('Mail.ReadWrite');
microsoftProvider.addScope('Calendars.ReadWrite');
microsoftProvider.addScope('Mail.Send');
microsoftProvider.addScope('openid');
microsoftProvider.addScope('profile');
microsoftProvider.addScope('User.Read');
microsoftProvider.addScope('User.Read.All');
microsoftProvider.addScope('offline_access');
microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters({'prompt': 'login'});

// Attempt to sign in with Microsoft to get the credential
final UserCredential? microsoftUserCredential =
    await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.linkWithPopup(microsoftProvider);

if (microsoftUserCredential?.credential != null) {

  debugPrint("User Level Refresh Token: ${user.refreshToken}");
  debugPrint(
    "Microsoft Level Refresh Token: ${microsoftUserCredential?.user?.refreshToken}",
  );

  var prefs = await _getPrefs();
  prefs.setString("ms_token_received_at", DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  prefs.setString(
      "ms_access_token", microsoftUserCredential!.credential!.accessToken!);

  Map<String, dynamic> accountData = {
    'default': 'false',
    'provider': 'microsoft',
    'phoneOrEmail':
        microsoftUserCredential.additionalUserInfo?.profile?['mail'],
    'accessToken': microsoftUserCredential.credential?.accessToken!,
    'idToken':
        (microsoftUserCredential.credential as OAuthCredential).idToken,
    'userRefreshToken': user.refreshToken,
    'providerRefreshToken': microsoftUserCredential.user?.refreshToken,
  };
  
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOfMaps =
      await getLinkedAccountsFromSharedPreferences();
  debugPrint("linkedAccounts: $listOfMaps");
  listOfMaps.add(accountData);
  saveLinkedAccountsToSharedPreferences(listOfMaps);
}
}

